# How to use Flexslider on different Wordpress pages?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I have a Wordpress theme (Max Mag) that uses Flexslider as a Featured Slider.

It displays posts based on a tag. You can only nominate one tag. It than appears on any page where a Homepage Blog Page template is assigned.

My question is: How do I get it to display different posts, depending on which page it is featured on.

Eg, on the Business page, it displays only business posts. On the Fashion page, only fashion posts.

It works like that in its demo (http://themeforest.net/item/max-mag-responsive-wordpress-magazine-theme/full_screen_preview/3103810) but I can't figure it out, and the developer variously says it requires extensive customisation, which I need to figure out myself, or all that's needed is to create a category page. That's not it because it works off a tag.

Anyway, any advice gratefully received.

Thanks ... Nick.

Answer (score 1):

it will better to use attcahments plugin.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/attachments

by this you can attach image by page or by post.

and at the fetching time you can configure this through flexslider.

thanks.